# Returning new object from function defined using Concepts

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-concepts

**Code**

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename N>
concept Number = std::is_arithmetic<N>::value;

template <typename T>
concept VectorXY = requires(T t)
{
    {t.x} -> Number;
    {t.y} -> Number;
};

template <Number N>
struct Vec2
{
    N x = 0;
    N y = 0;
};

VectorXY operator*(VectorXY v, Number n)
{
    return {v.x * n, v.y * n};
    // error: returning initializer list
}

int main()
{
    Vec2<float> v = Vec2<float>{} * 1;
    // error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'Vec2<float>' requested
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/gYsQ5B

---

**So how do I solve this?**

An explanation as to why the compiler can't infer the return type would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VectorXY` is not a type. It's a concept that's meant to check the type deduced from expression you return from the function. And said type deduction is entirely separate from deducing the type of the function's *parameter*.

What you return is

```
{v.x * n, v.y * n}
```

It's a braced enclosed initializer. When doing template argument deduction against it, what normally gets deduced is a `std::initializer_list`. The two problems with that is that first, the corresponding header is not included, so the program is ill-formed. And secondly, even if the header *was* included, `std::initializer_list<float>` does not satisfy the `VectorXY` concept.

You can fix it by specifying the type of the returned object, for instance via functional cast notation

```
return decltype(v){v.x * n, v.y * n};
```

Now it's a typed expression, against which the function's return type is deduced to something that satisfies the `VectorXY` concept.

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/5edQEt).

---

As an addendum, GCC doesn't implement it yet, but the correct syntax should be

```
VectorXY auto operator*(VectorXY auto v, Number auto n)
{
    return decltype(v){v.x * n, v.y * n};
}
```

Given the confusion that stems from just using `VectorXY`, I think the committee was right to require this constrained `auto` syntax instead. The fact there is a type deduction going on is more obvious to me here.